# How to test method that internally creates and uses a ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, testing, junit, serversocket

My server code looks something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable {   
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            // do stuff
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My plan was to write a mock client that connects to the server socket, and verifies the result, but in order to do that I need to know which port to connect to. However, this information is private.

None of the options I was thinking about are good practice I think:

1. If I use a predefined port number for the tests, I have no guarantee that it will be available. Even if it's available just before the test, it might be, theoretically snatched by the time I try to use it.
2. If I pass 0 as port number (so that `ServerSocket` will atomically provide a free port), I still have no access to it.
3. I could add a `getServerPort()` method to the interface or create a constructor that accepts a `ServerSocket` object, but changing the interface only for the sake of testing is considered bad practice.

Comment: Usually you use JUnit to test the functional aspect of the code, not whether or not the connection will work.  That is to say you separate `//do stuff` into its own function and write a test for that function so you don't have to work with passing a server port.

Comment: @SusannahPotts `// do stuff` is in a separate function, but that is private too... there is no public interface except a function that starts the server and a function that shuts it down.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes) might help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, your class is not really suited for unit test.

The problem is that your direct call to `new ServerSocket()` basically deprives your ability to **control** what the socket object will be doing.

So, what you can do:

```
interface SocketFactory {
  public ServerSocket createSocketFor(int port);
}

class SocketFactoryImpl implements SocketFactory {
...

public class Server implements Runnable {

  public Server(int port) {
    this(port, new SocketFactoryImpl());
  }

 Server(int port, SocketFactory socketFactory) {
   ...
```

In other words: you use *dependency injection* in order to provide a mean to your "class under test" to create those objects that it needs to do its work.

From there: you can use a mocking framework such as EasyMock in order to **control** what a **mocked** SocketFactory object will return (probably a **mocked** ServerSocket object). And now that you have full control over the ServerSocket used by your production code ... you can test whatever situation you want.

Long story short: don't call new; instead use dependency injection to gain **full** control over your class under test.

(and maybe watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to really understand what writing testable code is about).